# diff between == & Referencequals

Tags: c#, string

there is some diff between `== &` Referencequals

see following code:

```
string s1 = "1";
string s2 = string.Copy("1");

Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2));
Console.WriteLine(s1 == s2);
Console.Read();
```

The output is:

```
False
True
```

Can anybody explain this behaviour??

Comment: and `(object)s1 == (object)s2` returns false too :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ReferenceEquals` compares the references of the objects.

`==` can be overloaded to do whatever the type wants.  The *default* behavior for reference types, if it's not overloaded, is a comparison of the reference.  `String` overloaded the operator to do a value based comparison instead of a reference comparison.